# Bootstrap navbar not collapsing back

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I've been using bootstrap 4.3.1 for a [laravel project](https://github.com/User17745/Laravel-Blog) and everything is working good but the bottom navigation bar that I'm using, expanded once, does not want to collapse back while in mobile view.

[image: The HTML just changes back to being expanded instantly.]

As soon as I click the collapse button, code changes into being collapsed and then instantly goes back to being expended.

What could be the issue here?

Here's the code for the navigation bar:

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-bottom navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav m-auto">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/posts">Blog</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/services">Service</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/about">About</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <!-- Authentication Links -->
            @guest
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
            </li>
            @if (Route::has('register'))
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
                </li>
            @endif
        @else
            <li><a href="/posts/create" class="nav-item nav-link">Create Post</a></li>
            <li><a href="/dashboard" class="nav-item nav-link">{{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span></a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                    onclick="event.preventDefault();
                    document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();" class="nav-item nav-link">
                    {{ __('Logout') }}
                </a>
                <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                        @csrf
                </form>
            </li>
        @endguest
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Here's the HTML output of the above code from the browser:

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-bottom navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav m-auto">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/posts">Blog</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/services">Service</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/about">About</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="http://laravel.build/login">Login</a>
            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="http://laravel.build/register">Register</a>
                </li>
                            </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Content of my head tag:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Google Material Icons -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Aside from the code above, I also have bootstrap related scripts near the end of the body tag:

```
<!-- Bootstrap JS, Popper.js and jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your code into a new project and it worked fine. Can you show your Html Head element? Also, it appears you have 3 errors. Go to the console tab and see what they are.

Comment: @PatrickMcvay Those were just some minor unrelated errors. Got them fixed but unsurprisingly the problem remains. Added the required code in the OP.

Comment: It doesn't appear that you are pulling in the bootstrap css. try adding this to your head element <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

Comment: @PatrickMcvay, Sorry for such a late reply. I have bootstrap imported in my main sass file since I installed it using npm. Besides, this seems more like a JS issue.

Answer (score 7):

Some times it happens when you include bootstrap twice. Check your js files where bootstrap.js is referenced. Or include it globaly in webpack.mix.js [documentation](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/5.0/autoloading)

Comment: this solved my problem thank you, I was adding bootstrap in react twice, one in index.js and other in index.html

Comment: Another +1 this was also the case in my Rails project. I had declared it in the Webpacker but also declared it in application.erb